# How are the status of Azure deployment changed in the lifecycle

Tags: azure

I saw lots of available status exist during the life cycle of an [Azure Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx).

- Running
- Suspended
- RunningTransitioning
- SuspendedTransitioning
- Starting
- Suspending
- Deploying
- Deleting

But I can't find any document or read tell me about How these status be changed during the life cycle.

Could someone please tell me more detail about them. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge -

1. At the time of deployment initiation using `New-Deployment` -
   `Deploying` will be the status and then it will be changed to `Starting`
   status, finally to `Running` status.
2. Using `Set-AzureDeployment` you can
   set the status for example - `Suspended` and then use
   `Remove-AzureDeployment` for Deleting the deployment (`Deleting`-Status).
3. When we increase number instances (scaling) an existing deployment, then it will be first doing a `RunningTransitioning`

I have a small script written for you in Azure Powershell, which you can use and find out different status of deployment -

```
While(1) 
{
    Start-Sleep -s 3
    $serviceHealth = (Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName 'name' -Slot Production  -Verbose:$false)
    Write-Host "$($serviceHealth.Status)" -foregroundcolor "yellow"
}
```

Using this script when you can run following powershell cmds - 
Get-AzureDeployment
New-AzureDeployment
Remove-AzureDeployment
Set-AzureDeployment
Move-AzureDeployment
with different parameters, you can understand the status.

PS - you are right there was no proper documentation.